# Add EditText content to ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a button, an edittext and a ListView in my app. After the user clicks the button, I want to add the content of the edittext to the listview. How can I do this?

Comment: we are not here for sample code.

Comment: title and question are same ? :)P

Comment: I'm sure no one will ever understand what are you asking about.

Comment: FYI, **StackOverflow is not a Code repository**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below template of code.

```
EditText et;
Button bt;
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adpater;
// assign proper values to above variables
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
            String txt = et.getText().toString();
            adapter.add(txt);
       }
});
```

This is only main app logic, this code won't work directly. Many tutorials available in Internet for using Button, EditText, ListView. First write app for normal ListView behavior and finally use my logic to fulfill your requirements.

I hope you understand this and it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

For the adapter you need context, the row layout, the view ID where the data is and the data array.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mlist);
String[] data = new String[] { "one", "two" };


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, data);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For more info, see the tutorial [here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).

Answer (score -1):

Try this-

```
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView child = editText.getText().toString();
            _listview.addView(child);
            _listview.invalidate();
        }
    });
```